# Anchor Testing Workflow?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-client, testing, program-test

How do you guys go about testing?

1. Seems like program unit tests should be standard rust tests with `cargo test`.
2. There are some program tests that are run with `cargo test-bpf`.
3. Then test deployment, interactions, possible scenarios, etc with anchor in typescript.

Does this sound about right? What are common testing workflows?

Also, `anchor test` only builds for me. What is it supposed to do exactly?

Comment: My personal preference is to write Rust unit tests for branch coverage and testing sub-modules. I then write integration tests in Anchor, especially if I'm interacting with other programs.

Answer (score 2):

I mainly use `cargo test` for unit tests, and `anchor run <script in Anchor.toml>` for integration tests.

Scripts within `Anchor.toml` can be defined as follows:

```
[scripts]
my-tests = "ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json tests/myTests.ts"
```

And run with `anchor run my-tests`

The unit tests for those functions internal to the program, and the integration tests to verify that the constraints work as they should, throwing the corresponding errors (native or custom), as well as the normal operation of the program, instruction by instruction, and if there are instructions dependent on each other as well.

The way I organize integration testing in a large program goes something like this:

```
describe('Some general description of a process involving multiple instructions', () => {
  describe('My Instruction', () => {
    describe('Any situation where the corresponding instruction is tested.', () => {
      it('Any previous instruction required', async () => {
        // Code here
      });
      it('My Instruction', async () => {
        // Test here
      });
    });

    // ... other situations to test the same instruction

  });

  // ... other related instructions

});

describe('Errors', () => {
  describe('My Instruction', () => {
    describe('My Custom Error', () => {
      describe('Some description of the situation in which the error occurs.', () => {
        it('Any previous instruction required', async () => {
          // Code here
        });
        it('My Instruction fails', async () => {
          let error = null;
          try {
            // Cause error here
          } catch (e) {
            error = e;
          }
          // This way I make sure that an error has been caused and that it is the expected one.
          assert.equal(error, errors.MyProgram.MyCustomError);
        });
      });

      // ... repeat for each case where this error occurs

    });

    // ... repeat for each error that may occur in the instruction

  });

  // ... repeat for each instruction

});
```

Comment: This is great. Kinda what I was expecting. What about `cargo test-bpf`? I see in repos like Metaplex they use Rust Tokio for parallel testing some things and test-bpf runs these but cargo test does not. Looks like some higher level functionality on the lines of integ test for a program.

Wondering if anyone does this or the value in it? I think just doing things in TS would be best bc then I would also be scaffolding out some libs to interact with the program in TS as well.

Comment: I wouldn't know, I never used `cargo test-bpf`